# express-handlebars, render a hbs file without layout and with context

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

I'm using express.js with express-handlebars and I want to render an .hbs file without the default layout but with some context.

I can pass some context:

```
router.get('/catalog', function (req, res) {
    res.render('catalog/index.hbs', data);
});
```

I can deactivate default layout:

```
router.get('/catalog', function (req, res) {
    res.render('catalog/index.hbs', {layout: false});
});
```

but I can't do both at the same time:

```
router.get('/catalog', function (req, res) {
    res.render('catalog/index.hbs', data, {layout: false});
});
```

(tried switching the parameterst too).

On [express-handlebars docs](https://github.com/ericf/express-handlebars) I can't find a way to do both, what am I missing?

thank you.

EDIT: well... it seems that the answer was there in the docs within an advance topic example, I can do the following:

```
router.get('/catalog', function (req, res) {
    res.render('catalog/index.hbs', {catalog: data, layout: false});
});
```

So I can mix the data and the render options in the same object.